# How to force flex to buble default event

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

subj, i need to listen for TooltipEvent of my far child. Is that possible without manual re-dispatching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try listening at the capture phrase.  When adding the event listener in ActionScript there is an option to do so.  If you do this your event listener will fire before the handlers that fire during the target phase.

[Read a bit more about the event flow.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/16_Event_handling_4.html#118998)